# Is unique morphism `m` which maps "best" product type to "suboptimal" product type truly unique?

Tags: category-theory

I'm working through Bartosz Milewski's awesome blogs about category theory. I'm stuck on the one on [products and coproducts](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/07/products-and-coproducts/).

Bartosz says that a product of two objects `a` and `b` is the object `c` equipped with two projections such that for any other object `c'` equipped with two projections there is a unique morphism `m` from `c'` to `c` that factorizes those projections.

Of course we can find a suitable example in the category of sets and functions. The product of two types `Int` and `Bool` is the pair `(Int, Bool)`. The two projections are `p (int, _) = int` and `q (_, bool) = bool`. There is, however, another candidate for the product of `Int` and `Bool`: it is the type `Int` with projections `p' int = int` and `q' _ = True`. As Bartosz says: "That’s pretty lame, but it matches the criteria." Notice that the product type `Int` contains less values than the product type `(Int, Bool)`. Half as much, to be precise. Even though both product types can be mapped to the entire `Int` type, the product type `Int` can be mapped to only half of the `Bool` type. It is not *surjective* (if that is the right word for it)!

Because we can come up with a mormphism `m :: (Int, Bool) -> Int` (where `m` can only be *uniquely* implemented as `m (int, _) = int`) we know that the product type `(Int, Bool)` is better than `Int`. At this point I wonder: couldn't we just as easily implement `m` as `m (int, _) = int + 1`? Isn't that a second morphism that works? Or is that not allowed because the resulting product `Int` is actually not `Int` at all, but `Int` "shifted" by 1?

L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow in your `m` points in the wrong direction. We know that `(Int, Bool)` is "better" than `Int` because we have a morphism `m :: Int -> (Int, Bool)`, `m x = (x, True)`. It satisfies the conditions `p . m == p'` and `q . m == q'`, that's what is meant by `m` *factorizing* `p'` and `q'`. If you define `m` in any other way, this condition will not hold.

For example, if it was defined as `m x = (x + 1, True)`, then `p (m 0) == 1`, but `p' 0 == 0`.

Your map `m' :: (Int, Bool) -> Int`, if it factorized `p` and `q`, would point to `Int` being a suitable product, too. But the composition `q' . m' :: (Int, Bool) -> Bool` always returns `True`, so it cannot be equal to `q`.

Comment: Very clear! It seems like such an obvious mistake now that you point it out. Thank you!